# python error:builtin_function_or_method object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, python-2.6

It gives me an error at the last line

```
check_alert_json = [ ]

for k in check_job_stats_json.keys():

    if < > :
        check_alert_json.append[k]
```

In other code snippet iam trying: 
    if len(check_alert_json) > 0:
        check_job_altered = open(outputdir.rstrip('/')+"filename",'w+')
        check_job_altered.write(check_alert_json)

this gives me an error that argument 1 must be a string or read only character buffer,not a list

Comment: `append` is an instance method, you should be using parentheses to call it: `check_alert_json.append(k)`. Also, what is `if < > :` supposed to be doing?

Comment: If condition is checking for the timestamp,if it is latest-then append the data to check_alert_json

Comment: So you've deleted some of it? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
check_alert_json.append[k]
```

should be

```
check_alert_json.append(k)
```

(note the use of parentheses instead of square brackets.)

As to the second exception, `write()` expects a string or a character buffer, and you are giving it a list (`check_alert_json`). You need to define what exactly you're expecting to happen.